# Excel VBA to replace column values with another value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with around 3,000 rows. One of these columns contains ethnicity data but it is in numeric format, rather than text format, e.g.:

- 1 = American Indian or Alaskan Native
- 2 = Asian, Asian American, or Pacific Islander
- 3 = African American or Black
- 4 = Mexican or Mexican American

I'd like to write a module in VBA that uses a Select Case (or...?) to swap out the values in this column from the integer to text. Can someone show me how to accomplish this?

Comment: @Mikeb's comment on VLookUp sounds like the best bet, but if it does not suit, you may wish to look at ADO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heres a quick VBA mashup that will replace your Current Selection values with substitutes:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Sub ReplaceData()

    Dim RangeCells As Range

    Dim LookupArray(4) As String, RangeCell As Range

    LookupArray(1) = "Test A"
    LookupArray(2) = "Test B"
    LookupArray(3) = "Test C"
    LookupArray(4) = "Test D"

    For Each RangeCell In Selection

        If IsNumeric(RangeCell.Value) And RangeCell.Value <= UBound(LookupArray) And RangeCell.Value >= LBound(LookupArray) Then
            RangeCell.Value = LookupArray(Val(RangeCell.Value))
        End If

    Next RangeCell

End Sub
```

Assumptions: all possible cell values are covered in array index. Otherwise select case is probably what you want to switch to. Let me know if you can't figure how to switch to that.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. Can I just add this to a new module or does it need to go under Sheet1 or ThisWorkbook (I'm very new at VBA)? How exactly do I get this module to run against the selected column?

Comment: well I ran it by dropping this in a module and then using run macro dialog while i had my desired selection set in sheet. Probably the easiest way of doing it. Or you can hard-code the range of RangeCells variable with a `Set RangeCells = Sheet1.Range("A1:A4")`  just after `Dim RangeCells as Range` line

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The only problem I'm having now is a "type mismatch" error when I run the code from the line RanngeCell.Value = LookupArray(RangeCell.Value)

Comment: That would imply the cell has a value that isn't numeric. I'll update the code to make it more robust. Will also compensate if you end up going outside the range of array index.

Answer (score 6):

A non VBA (simpler, in my opinion) approach in Excel would be to create a lookup table with that data - the integer in the first column, and the text in the second, and then in the column next to your data, use VLOOKUP to find the corresponding text.

Comment: Right ! no need to VBA for that

Answer (score 0):

To do something like VLOOKUP, but with replacement you can try the below

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceData()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ABCArray() As Variant, DEFArray As Variant

    ABCArray = Array("A", "b", "C")
    DEFArray = Array("D", "E", "F")

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

        For i = LBound(ABCArray) To UBound(ABCArray)

            .Replace What:=ABCArray(i), _
            Replacement:=DEFArray(i), _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            MatchCase:=False

        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

I cannot agree with VLOOKUP being better for one simple reason: we do macros to automate repeating actions and I assume someone is looking for macro solution mostly in cases like that.